# Node.js Update Table with Array in Mysql

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I have this table.

[image]

My datas are below to put this table above.

```
buffer= [{deviceId: 000002, input2:false, input3:false, input4:false, input5:false, input6:false, input7:false, input8:false, output1:false, output2:false, output3:false, output4:false, output5:false, output6:false, output7:false, output8:false},
{deviceId: 000001, input2:false, input3:false, input4:false, input5:false, input6:false, input7:false, input8:false, output1:false, output2:false, output3:false, output4:false, output5:false, output6:false, output7:false, output8:false}]
```

I'm tring to put my data with this query

```
dbConnect.query("update datas set input1=?, input2=?, input3=?, input4=?, input5=?, input6=?, input7=?, input8=?, output1=?, output2=?, output3=?, output4=?, output5=?, output6=?, output7=?, output8=? where deviceId=?", [buffer],
function (err, rows, fields) {
     if (!err) {
        console.log("OK")
       } else {
        console.log("ERROR")
    }
})
```

Also error is below

> sqlMessage: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual
> that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to
> use near ''000002', input2=?, input3=?, input4=?, input5=?, input6=?,
> input7=?, input8=?, ' at line 1",   sqlState: '42000',   index: 0,
> sql: "update datas set input1='[object Object]', '000002', input2=?,
> input3=?, input4=?, input5=?, input6=?, input7=?, input8=?, output1=?,
> output2=?, output3=?, output4=?, output5=?, output6=?, output7=?,
> output8=? where deviceId=?"

I need your help, Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found solution of my problem. need to use

```
insert into TABLENAME(key, column1, column2, ...) values (?),(?),... on duplicate key update column1=value(column1), column2=value(column2), ...;
```

but there is one detail, that is `key` column have to be `unique index`