# MySQL - UPDATE <table> SET (n<values>) WHERE <table>.`foreign_key`

Tags: mysql, sql

Just to get the elephant out of the room since there are so many SO questions similar to this. I have looked through the other posts with similar names and did not find what I was looking for. That being said I may have just not seen how to implement their question to my specific implementation

I am trying to update multiple rows in a table to all [potentially] different values but I don't know how many rows I will be updating as I am targeting using a foreign key. However, due to database constraints it is safe to assume that I have the correct number of inputs. (e.g. 3 values for 3 rows, or 5 values for 5 rows) AND even if it was not safe to assume, I don't mind an error being thrown as that would insure data integrity if something did happen to be wrong...

It does not matter which values get assigned to which rows.

Here is some examples of what I have tried.

```sql
UPDATE table1 
SET 
    table1.column1 IN (17 , 37, 62)
WHERE
    table1.foreign_key = 877;
```

After that I found out you can't use IN like that...
Then I tried:

```sql
UPDATE table1 
SET 
    table1.column1 = (17 , 37, 62)
WHERE
    table1.primary_key IN (SELECT 
            primary_key
        FROM
            table1
        WHERE
            foreign_key = 877);
```

However, "You can't specify target table 'table1' for update in FROM clause"

This would be fairly trivial to do with a SELECT then an update after (n_rows + 1 queries) (shown below), so I am assuming it is possible to do in one query.

```sql
SELECT primary_key from table1 where foreign_key = ?;,[877]
```

Then mapping the values and primary keys (I am using nodejs backend)

```sql
UPDATE table1 set column1 = ? where primary_key = ?;,[value1,primary_key1]
```

The hard parts seem to be

1. How to map multiple values to multiple rows.
2. How to get the unique IDs for each row at run time.

I don't mind if I have to use a stored procedure, I just really don't want to send n+1 queries to the database.

Answer (score 1):

you need to update your datas with just one query like this below.

```
insert into TABLENAME(key, column1, column2, ...) values (?),(?),... on duplicate key update column1=value(column1), column2=value(column2), ...;
```

also you can visit my post with this link.

[Node.js Update Table with Array in Mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66999309/node-js-update-table-with-array-in-mysql)

I had same problem 2 days ago.

Comment: Uhh, I don't know the primary key of the rows I am trying to update (I can query for them though) so this doesn't actually let me complete it in 1 query, I would still have to do 2 queries. But I forgot I could use arrays like that so at least this problem isn't exactly O(n+1) assuming node mysql isn't doing that behind the scenes.

Comment: you don't need primary key. I even removed primary key from my table. You can think this query reason like this. you have some devices. and devices send to data to your server. But you dont want to insert new rows to data table. because there is that devices data already. you can use this query to put your data to paste to existing row by deviceId.